# response.sendRedirect not working between Java and AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, servlets

I am trying to set up a login page for my website, however at the moment I am stuck on the `sendRedirect` method, as it doesn't appear to load a new page when required.

My login page is a .jsp file that passes the username and password information via AngularJS `$scope` to the servlet, which contains the following code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    System.out.println("Redirecting...");
    response.sendRedirect("https://www.youtube.com/");
    return;
}
```

The `System.out.println("Redirecting...");` works, however it does not redirect to the URL provided, no matter what that is. I have read other advice which mentioned to add the `return;` line, and I have tried other URLs specific to my project (e.g. `index.jsp`, `\index.jsp`, etc.), however none of these have made a difference and it still does not work.

Would `window.location` be a more suitable approach for this? What code should I be modifying here?

Comment: Define _doesn't work_. Why do you expect your page to redirect, rather than the request sent through AngularJS? When you check the status code of the response in your browser's network console, what is it?

Comment: I mean that the browser doesn't redirect from the login page to whatever it is that I specify in the `response.sendRedirect` method (e.g. youtube.com, index.jsp, etc.)

Comment: And why should it?

Comment: Does this have to do with my response being sent to AngularJS? I am not really understanding what the problem is.

Comment: Right. Your request is sent asynchronously. You likely have a callback in the AngularJS code where you have access to the response. If the client doesn't follow redirects, you'll have access to the `Location` header and you can move your `window.location`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've made the webpage finally redirect correctly and I'm posting this just in case someone else stumbles upon the same issue.

As mentioned in previous comments, the response should be sent from the Java servlet to AngularJS, I have made the redirection occur as follows in my `logincontroller.js` file:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function LoginController($scope, $http, $window)
{
    $scope.login = function()
    {
        $http({
            url: 'login',
            method: 'POST',
            data:
            {
                'username': $scope.username,
                'password': $scope.password
            }
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("SUCCESS! Data: " + data);
                $scope.details = data;
                $window.location.href = "home.jsp"; //This line redirects.
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert('ERROR!');
        });
    };
};
```